# Errors in pom file spring versions

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml

I have uploaded my pom file here

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ryuetva8gintpf5/pom.xml?dl=0

I am seeing a lot of strange errors, one of them being this [Multiple ContextLoader definitions in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479859/multiple-contextloader-definitions-in-web-xml) and I was wondering if there is a mismatch in my Spring version between core, mvc, security etc which is causing this. I don't know too much about which version is compatible with what so if someone can review my pom file and let me know if there are any compatibility issues with my pom.xml that would be great.

Comment: For starters stop mixing jars of different spring version, you are mixing 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.4 and 4.1.6 and what not more due to other dependencies pulling in different versions.

Comment: So my question is since the highest number is 4.2.4 can I use 4.2.4 for all the Spring components/jars in my application?

Comment: Regardless of the version you must use the same versions to avoid api/class conflicts... Doesn't matter which version you use as long as you use a single version.

Answer (score 0):

Please just copy paste your `pom.xml` in here, it will be more easier to reviewed.

Actually, you could use [spring initializr](https://start.spring.io/) to save your life for manage spring dependency, but from your `pom.xml` I found some mistake, you initialize a dependency version with variable but I could see you declare the name of your variable.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

So, either you define your variable name in `<properties>`.

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```

Or, you could declare your spring version like this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

My advice choose one method, and keep up with it for the sake of easy maintenance

Comment: I agree that it's not the best way to do it but I don't believe it is an error. Seems like it's more of a best practice or a common way of doing things. In any case, I am looking to see if anything I have there can actually cause my code to throw any run time errors/exceptions because of version no mismatches.